# manual implementation of Gaussian naive bayesian returns posterior larger than 1

Tags: r, bayesian, naive-bayes

I try to implement Gaussian naive bayesian manually in R. I test my model on `iris` data set. I would like to build a predictive model. That is, I would like to consider, for each point, the correct class.

### My problem:

I see that the posteriors for some points are larger than 1, which is wrong.

### What I have tried:

- I have divided the data into training and test datasets.
- Then I assume equally prior for each class (`0.3`) (as the prior must sum to one).
- I applied the Bayesian rule for the training data set. For this I do the following:
- to compute the likelihood for each class, I computed the density (for each point in each class). `den[[1]]` is the density of the
  `Sepal.Length`. `den[2]` is the density of `Sepal.Width.` `den[[3]]` and `den[[4]]` are the density for the resining variables.
- Then to compute the posterior for each point, I computed `prior*likelihood`, for each point.

However, I found that some posteriors values are larger than one. I believe I did something wrong, but do not know what is my mistake?

Any help, please?

### Here is my code

```
data(iris)
dim(iris)[[1]]
##split the data based on its class
NewData <- split(iris, iris$Species)
## divide the data based on their class
NewDatSetosa <- NewData$setosa[,1:4]
NewDatVersicolor <- NewData$versicolor[,1:4]
NewDatVirginica <- NewData$virginica[,1:4]

##divide the data into train and test datasets
set.seed(1234)
datadivision <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.33))
iris.training <- iris[datadivision==1, 1:4]
iris.test <- iris[datadivision==2, 1:4]
##Compute the posterior for each class

posterior <- function(data,prior,newDat){
  post <- list()
##compute the density for each point in the training data set
  den <- lapply(1:4, function(i) dnorm(data[[i]], mean(newDat[[i]]), sd(newDat[[i]])))
## compute the posterior for each point. den[[1]] is the density of the 
##Sepal.Length. den[2] is the density of Sepal.Width. den[3] and den[4] ##are the density for the resining variables.

     post <- prior*den[[1]]*den[[2]]*den[[3]]*den[[4]]
  return(post)
}
post.Setosa <- posterior(iris.training, prior=0.3, NewDatSetosa)
post.Versicolor <- posterior(iris.training, prior=0.3, NewDatVersicolor)
post.Virginica <- posterior(iris.training, prior=0.3, NewDatVirginica)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing, but why would a normal distribution (not restricted to [0, 1]) for the likelihood make sense, if you expect an posterior to have something to do with a probability of class membership?

Comment: @Björn   As I understand the normal distribution must be estimated for each class. I tried to do a classification problem. So, I estimate the normal distribution for each class and then apply the Bayesian rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your priors should be $1/3$, not `0.3`. But, this is the minor issue. It's true that your posterior, i.e. $p(c|x)$, where $c$ represents the class can't be larger than $1$. However, it's not equal to `prior * likelihood`; rather it is *proportional to* it:
$$p(c|x)=\frac{p(x|c)p(c)}{p(x)}\propto p(x|c)p(c)$$
So, what you've calculated is not a valid PDF or PMF. It should be normalized by $p(x)=\sum_{c_i} p(x|c_i)p(c_i)$. But, you can do the classification w/o the normalization step because $p(x)$ doesn't depend on specific $c_i$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Hence, I need to divide `prior*den[[1]]*den[[2]]*den[[3]]*den[[4]]` by the their sum.

Comment: @Mary , yes sum wrt each class.